# Getting #ERROR! Message when combining valid formulas

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, sum, nested-if, ifs

I am trying to setup a formula in one line that will calculate the proper date that a contract can be cancelled based on the Texas Addendum for Property Subject to Mandatory Owner's Association.  Depending on 3 possible selections, Section A1, Section A2, or Section A3, the calculations for the possible termination of a contract vary.
My formula's work on their own, but not when combined into one long if statement.

Here are the 3 formula's.  All work properly on their own.

```
=if(E12="A1",if(B17="",B20,B17+3),)
=if(E12="A2",if(B17="","",B17+3),)
=if(E12="A3",if(B17="",B20,""),)
```

However, when combined into one statement I get an #ERROR!.
I've tried multiple ways to write the formula but all get the same #ERROR!.

```
=if((E12="A2",if(B17="","",B17+3)),if(e12="A1",if(B17="",B20,B17+3)),if(E12="A3",if(B17="",B20,"")),)
=if((E12="A2",if(B17="","",B17+3)),if(e12="A1",if(B17="",B20,B17+3)),if(E12="A3",if(B17="",B20,""),))
=if((E12="A2",if(B17="","",B17+3),),if(e12="A1",if(B17="",B20,B17+3),),if(E12="A3",if(B17="",B20,""),))
```

Currently this is working as is as I have a final calculation in the necessary cell that takes the one value greater than zero.

```
=if(D31>0,D31,if(D32>0,D32,if(D33>0,D33)))
```

But it's not as clean as I'd like to have it.  I'd prefer to have this as one single line calculation instead of in 4 different cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

proper nesting is done like this:

```
=IF(E12="A1", IF(B17="", B20, B17+3),
 IF(E12="A2", IF(B17="",, B17+3),
 IF(E12="A3", IF(B17="", B20, ), )))
```

Comment: Ah, thank you.  I just had too many parentheses.